# Cut a file between two lines numbers using awk

Tags: text, awk, text-processing

Say I have a file with 100 lines (not including header). I want to cut that file down, only keeping the content between line 51 and 70 (inclusive), as well as the header so that the resulting file is 20+1 lines.

So far, I have this code:

```
awk 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} (NR-1)>50 && (NR-1)<71 {filename = "file20.csv"; print h >> filename} {print >> filename}' file100.csv
```

But it's giving me an error:

> fatal: expression for `>>' redirection has null string value

Can somebody help me understand where my syntax is wrong?

Comment: The reason for your error: on line #2, you execute this `{print >> filename}` where the "filename" variable is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use:

```
awk 'NR==1 || (NR>=51 && NR<=70)'
```

Note that this evaluates the condition of `NR`. In case it is true, it performs awk's default action: `{print $0}`. Hence, you do not have to explicit it.

Then you can redirect to another file:

```
awk 'NR==1 || (NR>=51 && NR<=70)' file > new_file
```

#### Test

```
$ seq 100 | awk 'NR==1 || (NR>=51 && NR<=70)'
1
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
```

It returns 21 lines:

```
$ seq 100 | awk 'NR==1 || (NR>=51 && NR<=70)' | wc -l
21
```

Comment: Ok, just did that. As an aside, do you know why the code in my original post is not working?

Comment: @Y.C.Wu I am checking. It is not clear to me why you set `filename` on every case when `NR` is in the desired range. Probably you are trying to write to `filename` when it is still not set. EDIT: now I see glenn jackman commented it!